# Enforce REAL non-nullable string reference type

Tags: c#, string, .net-core, c#-8.0, nullable-reference-types

I've just tried the new [C# 8 Nullable Reference Type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references), which allows us to use non-nullable strings.

In my `.csproj` (.NET Core 3.1) I set this:

```cs
<Nullable>enable</Nullable>
```

I created a `FooClass` as follows:

```cs
public class FooClass
{
    public FooClass(string testString, DateTime testDate)
    {
        if (testString == null || testString == string.Empty)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(testString));
        else if (testDate == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(testDate));

        MyString = testString;
        MyDate = testDate;
    }

    public string MyString { get; }
    public DateTime MyDate { get; }
}
```

However, when I create a new instance of my class in my `Main()` with `null` values on purpose:

```cs
var test = new FooClass(testString:null, testDate:null);
```

The compiler is fine with the `testString` parameter, but with the `testDate` parameter it tells me:

> Argument 2: cannot convert from '`<null>`' to '`DateTime`'

How can I get the same behavior for the first argument?

My `testString` parameter is a non-nullable reference type, just like `testDate`. As I didn't declare it as `string?`, I'm expecting the compiler to behave the same way for both parameters.

Is there another feature to activate to enforce *real* non-nullable strings in C#?

Comment: _"The compiler is fine"_ - you're supposed to get a compiler warning. Does that happen?

Comment: `warning CS8625: Cannot convert null literal to non-nullable reference type.` it shows this (after you remove `null` from `testdate`). You can threat warning as errors to get a compilation error here

Comment: Can you verify whether you get a warning message about `testString`?

Comment: I got the warning message only after I give a `DateTime` object to my `testString` parameter. If I give it `null` the warning message isn't showing up

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add `TreatWarningsAsErrors` option to your `csproj` file

```
<TreatWarningsAsErrors>true</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
```

or add `CS8625` warning to `WarningsAsErrors` list

```
<WarningsAsErrors>NU1605;CS8625</WarningsAsErrors>
```

And this code will generate an expected error

```cs
var test = new FooClass(testString: null, testDate: default);
```

> error CS8625: Cannot convert null literal to non-nullable reference type.

Nullable reference types are implemented as type annotations in CLR, this can be a reason that compiler shows you an error with `testDate` in your original sample first.

```cs
var test = new FooClass(testString: null, testDate: null);
```

When you get rid of this error, you'll see the expected behavior with nullable references errors/warnings

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this is exactly what I was looking for. Instead of treating all warnings as error I just added this one to the existing one `<WarningsAsErrors>NU1605;CS8625</WarningsAsErrors>`

Comment: @JérômeMEVEL yes, that also works. will update the answer